# How can I add a "Go to Line" Action to a SourceViewer

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jface

I have implemented an Eclipse plugin that uses a SourceViewer in an own ViewPart to present some code. In this ViewPart I would like to have a "Go to Line" action. I could implement my own action (resp. command) and add it to the menubar but I think it would be better to reuse the existing function if possible.

My questions: is it possible to use the standard navigate menu options in a SourceViewer and how can I enable them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Goto Line action is added to the Navigate menu by individual editors in their `EditorActionBarContributor` class so you can't reuse this.

There is a standard 'command' with id `org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.goto.line` for Goto Line with a key binding to Ctrl+L